# connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ssh, connection, vagrant

I created a Ubuntu Vagrant box and ssh'd into it.

Now, created a ssh key and trying to ssh to my localhost but I get the following error.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ssh -vvvv localhost 
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

When I check the list of ports opened as follows:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn|grep 22
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:22            0.0.0.0:*               
LISTEN      11598/sshd
```

I see the ip address as 10.0.2.15:22. Also, my sshd service is running as well.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ps aux|grep ssh
root     11430  0.0  0.7  68084  3688 ?        Ss   17:41   0:00 sshd: vagrant [priv]
vagrant  11432  0.0  0.3  68216  1908 ?        S    17:41   0:00 sshd: vagrant@pts/0 
root     11598  0.0  0.6  61388  3060 ?        Ss   17:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Comment: Have You checked firewall rules and allowed connections on port 22 ?

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377375/failed-to-connect-to-host-via-ssh-on-vagrant-with-ansible-playbook : "Most likely because you never configured the account on your machine to accept the key from itself. Using defaults, you'd need to add the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys." (Give it a shot!) Of course verify the permissions as well. Check https://web.archive.org/web/20140327182105/http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#3.14

Comment: @Novice that would *not* give a connection refused. That would give an authentication error/failure. Connection refused broadly speaking means that the packets never reached their intended destination, and the first place to look is in the network layer.

Comment: @vidarlo, thanks for noticing that, I might have misread the scenario here.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ssh -vvvv localhost
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn|grep 22
> tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:22            0.0.0.0:*
> ```

The line 10.0.2.15:22 tells ut that something is listening on port 22 on 10.0.2.15. However, you try to `ssh localhost`. Localhost is 127.0.0.1 (or ::1 for IPv6). From what information you provide, nothing listens to port 22 on the loopback interface.

Thus `ssh localhost` does not work. `ssh 10.0.2.15` will probably work.

If a socket listens to a specific interface, it will only receive packets destined for that interface. A socket can listen to the wildcard 0.0.0.0, which means it will receive packets on that port on any interface. A process listening at 0.0.0.0 can be accessed both by the localhost and the network address of the host.

Comment: The machine I'm trying to run `ssh localhost` on is actually a ubuntu VM that I connect thru ssh. Could that be the reason?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Did you ask the original question  two years ago, or are you asking another, but very similar question? If you asked the question in 2017, is the output still valid? If not, please ask a new question and describe the problem in as much detail as possible.